# Store and retrieve search results

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, zend-framework

I'm a bit stuck with a piece of code. I have a search field which calls a PHP function which looks into the database:

```
$this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
$q = $this->getRequest()->getParam('q');

 $product_db = new Products();
 $this->view->products = $product_db->searchProduct($q);
 foreach($this->view->products as $product)
 {
      ....
 }
```

The result of this gets loaded into my HTML page via JQuery:

```
var searchItem = function() {
    if($('#json_search').val())
    {
        $('#search-resultlist').load('/search/quick/q/'+ $('#json_search').val() );
    }
    else {
        $('#search-resultlist').html('');
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="right-searchcontent" >
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search ... " id="json_search">
</div>
<div class="right-searchresult">
  <ul id="search-resultlist" >
    <li >

    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Now basically what I try to achieve is to create a 'search history'.
At first I tried it with a SESSION array in my search controller:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['history'])) {
  $_SESSION['history'] = array();
}
```

And in my function to show the database search results:

```
if(!empty($product)){
  if(!in_array($product->naam, $_SESSION['history']))
  {
    $_SESSION['history'][] = $product->naam;
  }
 }
```

But this was storing ALL the values I ever searched for (like: 'sk', 'ah')
I just want the values I actually clicked on.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

I've been trying to achieve my result with localStorage, but this wasn't going to give me the right solution. Also I tried using Cookies with this function:

```
var cookieList = function(cookieName) {
    var cookie = $.cookie(cookieName);
    var items = cookie ? cookie.split(/,/) : new Array();

    return {
        "add": function(val) {
            //Add to the items.
            items.push(val);
            //Save the items to a cookie.
            $.cookie(cookieName, items.join(','));
        },
        "remove": function (val) {
            indx = items.indexOf(val);
            if(indx!=-1) items.splice(indx, 1);
            $.cookie(cookieName, items.join(','));        },
        "clear": function() {
            items = null;
            //clear the cookie.
            $.cookie(cookieName, null);
        },
        "items": function() {
            return items;
        }
      }
}
```

But when I tried to alert list.items it just returned me the whole method.

I can achieve the product name when I click it, but I just don't know how I can store this into a SESSION or something else what I can achieve any time on any page..

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.searchItem', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var search = $(this).attr('value'));
});
```

Comment: you can use jQuery and cookies to store the ones that are clicked in cookies

Comment: I have been playing around with Cookies this morning, but I couldn't get it the right way. I edited my question and added the function I used for the cookies.

Comment: `alert(list.items())` and not `alert(list.items)`

Comment: Oh haha, what a stupide mistake of me! Thanks for pointing this out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'ts been fixed with the function I already had:

```
var cookieList = function(cookieName) {
    var cookie = $.cookie(cookieName);
    var items = cookie ? cookie.split(/,/) : new Array();

    return {
        "add": function(val) {
            //Add to the items.
            items.push(val);
            //Save the items to a cookie.
            $.cookie(cookieName, items.join(','));
        },
        "contain": function (val) {
        //Check if an item is there.
        if (!Array.prototype.indexOf) {
            Array.prototype.indexOf = function(obj, start) {
                for (var i = (start || 0), j = this.length; i < j; i++) {
                    if (this[i] === obj) { return i; }
                }
                return -1;
            };
        }
        var indx = items.join(',').indexOf(val);
        if(indx > -1){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }                                                 },
        "remove": function (val) {
            indx = items.indexOf(val);
            if(indx!=-1) items.splice(indx, 1);
            $.cookie(cookieName, items.join(','));        },
        "clear": function() {
            items = null;
            //clear the cookie.
            $.cookie(cookieName, null);
        },
        "items": function() {
            return items;
        }
    }
}
```

When someone clicks on a search result it's added to the cookie list:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.searchItem', function(e){
  var search = $(this).attr('value');
  var list = new cookieList("MyItems");
  if(!list.contain(search)){
    list.add(search);
  }
});
```

And when opening the search box I show the results of the list:

```
jQuery.each(list.items(), function(index, value){
  ....
});
```

Maybe this will help someone out sometime..